# How to query for suggested books like amazon does?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I'm working on developing a web portal for a bookstore, and I want to have the ability to suggest books to a user.

I want something similar to amazon.com, when a user orders book A, the system should provide a list of other suggested books. Book B is suggested if there exists a user Bob that bought both A and B. Additionally, I want my system to return the suggested books sorted on decreasing sales count, and only count sales to users that have bought both books (like Bob).

Here are the important tables:

Book(ISBN, title, publicationYear, etc..)

Orders(orderID, loginName, date)

BooksOrdered(orderID, ISBN, count)

This query is more complex than anything I've previously tried.

Current thoughts:

First find all the users that have ordered the same book (ISBN)

> 1. Join all three tables on Book.ISBN = BooksOrdered.ISBN AND Orders.orderID = BooksOrdered.ISBN
> 2. WHERE Book.ISBN = bookInQuestionISBN
> 3. GROUP BY Orders.loginName
> 4. Project out loginName

So something like:

```
SELECT Orders.loginName as otherBuyerLoginName
FROM Book, Orders, BooksOrdered,
WHERE Book.ISBN = bookInQuestionISBN AND Orders.orderID = BooksOrdered.ISBN
GROUP BY Orders.loginName
```

Then I could grab all the books these loginNames have ordered, group them by loginName, sum count and ORDER BY DESC SUM(BooksOrdered.count).

However, I'm thinking that the first result will most likely be the book in question. I don't want to suggest the same book the user has just bought.

What do you suggest? Maybe I should start over from scratch?

EDIT:

Here is some data:

BooksOrdered contains:

```
orderID ISBN        count
    3   FakeISBN    3
    7   FakeISBN    3
    8   FakeISBN    100
    11  FakeISBN2   40
    7   FakeISBN2   4
    10  FakeISBN2   20
    10  FakeISBN3   34
    11  TesterISBN  3
    9   TesterISBN  1
```

Orders contains:

```
orderID loginName  date
2       Tester     2012-03-15 19:43:27
3       Tester     2012-03-16 15:56:55
6       Tester2    2012-03-16 17:28:02
7       Tester     2012-03-16 17:31:21
8       ni3hao3    2012-03-16 23:18:15
9       ni3hao3    2012-03-17 13:12:38
10      ni3hao3    2012-03-17 13:13:55
11      Bobby      2012-03-17 13:28:14
```

Alright, now I want to know the top suggestions for the book with ISBN = "TesterISBN"

Two people have ordered "TesterISBN": ni3hao3 and Bobby

ni3hao3's total sales history:

```
1 copy of "TesterISBN"
100 copies of "FakeISBN"
20 copies of "FakeISBN2"
34 copies of "FakeISBN3"
```

Bobby's total sales history:

```
3 copies of "TesterISBN"
40 copies of "FakeISBN2"
```

So the totals of sales for purchasers of "TesterISBN" are as follows:

```
4 copies of "TesterISBN"
100 copies of "FakeISBN"
60 copies of "FakeISBN2"
34 copies of "FakeISBN3"
```

So I'd like the results to return:

```
FakeISBN
FakeISBN2
FakeISBN3
```

In that order.

EDIT:

I believe I've figured it out:

```
SELECT Bo.ISBN, B.title, SUM(Bo.count) 
FROM BooksOrdered Bo, Orders O, Book B
WHERE Bo.orderID = O.orderID AND Bo.ISBN = B.ISBN
                            AND Bo.ISBN != 'TesterISBN'
                            AND O.loginName IN ( SELECT DISTINCT(Orders.loginName) as otherBuyerLoginName
                            FROM Orders, BooksOrdered
                            WHERE BooksOrdered.ISBN = 'TesterISBN' 
                                AND Orders.orderID = BooksOrdered.orderID)
GROUP BY Bo.ISBN
ORDER BY SUM(Bo.count) DESC
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT Bo.ISBN, B.title, SUM(Bo.count) 
FROM BooksOrdered Bo, Orders O, Book B
WHERE Bo.orderID = O.orderID AND Bo.ISBN = B.ISBN
                            AND Bo.ISBN != 'TesterISBN'
                            AND O.loginName IN ( SELECT DISTINCT(Orders.loginName) as otherBuyerLoginName
                            FROM Orders, BooksOrdered
                            WHERE BooksOrdered.ISBN = 'TesterISBN' 
                                AND Orders.orderID = BooksOrdered.orderID)
GROUP BY Bo.ISBN
ORDER BY SUM(Bo.count) DESC
```

This seems to do the trick

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you can approach this in two steps:

1. Find which users bought the book in question and get the ids of all their orders
2. Group all other books in those orders by ISBN and count number of occurrences (i.e. number of orders they have been bought together with the book in question)

It would translate to something like this:

```
SELECT bo.ISBN, COUNT(*) AS timesBoughtTogether
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT(o.orderID) FROM Orders o
      LEFT JOIN BooksOrdered bo ON o.orderID = bo.orderID
      WHERE bo.ISBN = 'ISBN to provide suggestions for') relevantOrders
LEFT JOIN BooksOrdered bo ON relevantOrders.orderID = bo.orderID
WHERE bo.ISBN != 'ISBN to provide suggestions for'
GROYP BY bo.ISBN
ORDER BY timesBoughtTogether DESC
```

I didn't actually run this, so I hope the syntax isn't off.

Comment: That is one awesome query! I'm working on building a quick test for it (brb). Thanks for the quick response btw :)

Comment: Alright, so it doesn't seem to be working. It returns an empty set. Also, shouldn't we be thinking about all of the orders placed by those users who have also purchased 'ISBN to provide suggestions for'? Instead of just the other books in a particular order by a particular user?

Comment: This query is meant to work on all orders that contained the particular ISBN, not one order of one user. There is only one placeholder for a variable (which appears twice). I 'm not sure exactly what you are doing, so it might be a good idea to update the question and provide some real data and the actual queries you are giving.

Comment: @Silver: I realized I had the wrong thing in mind -- my first take would only work if the "related" books were bought *as part of the same order*. Try the updated one instead.

Comment: This is closer! It returns:
FakeISBN2 1
Which is correct in terms of highest ranking according to other books ordered in the same order, just not the highest ranking according to other books ordered by users that have also ordered 'TesterISBN'. I think I figured it out though, check my answer. You helped me get to the answer, thank you for that :)

Answer (score 0):

I've written this on SQL Server, but converting to MySQL syntax should be trivial.

This query returns recommendations based on books in the `orderID` in question (`@currentOrderID`):

```
select b.ISBN, b.title, sum(bo.count) as ranking
from Book b inner join 
    BooksOrdered bo on b.ISBN = bo.ISBN inner join
    (   select distinct orderID
        from BooksOrdered bo
        where bo.ISBN in (  select ISBN
                            from BooksOrdered bo1
                            where bo1.orderID = @currentOrderID )
    ) o on bo.orderID = o.orderID
where b.ISBN not in ( select ISBN
                      from BooksOrdered bo1
                      where bo1.orderID = @currentOrderID )
group by b.ISBN, b.title
order by sum(bo.count) desc
```

This one returns recommendations based on the entire order history of the login that made the current order:

```
select b.ISBN, b.title, sum(bo.count) as ranking
from Book b inner join 
    BooksOrdered bo on b.ISBN = bo.ISBN inner join
    (   select bo.orderID
        from BooksOrdered bo
        where bo.ISBN in (  select ISBN
                            from BooksOrdered bo1
                            where bo1.orderID = @currentOrderID )
    ) o on bo.orderID = o.orderID
where b.ISBN not in (   select ISBN
                        from Orders o inner join
                            BooksOrdered bo on o.orderID = bo.orderID
                        where o.loginName = (   select loginName
                                                from Orders
                                                where orderID = @currentOrderID ) )
group by b.ISBN, b.title
order by sum(bo.count) desc
```

Hope these give you what you're looking for!

Comment: I think this is pretty much what I was going for, although I can't get it to work. Problem is I know the ISBN, but not the orderIDs (at least not directly). I think I figured out the problem though (see latest edit at the bottom of my question).